# how can i change proxy country with selenium and bright data proxy manager?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, python-requests, proxy

How to control targeting dynamically?
You don't have to specify the country, state or city targeting in advance using the Targeting tab in the UI. It is possible to pass extra targeting options dynamically ('on the fly') along with the request.

```
curl -x lum-country-br@127.0.0.1:24001 http://lumtest.com/myip.json
```

The request's structure is:

```
curl -x lum-country-{COUNTRY-ISO-CODE}@{IP}:{PORT}{DESTINATION-URL}
```

The other option for controlling targeting dynamically is by including a special header.

```
"x-lpm-country: {COUNTRY_CODE}"
```

Example request could look like this:

```
curl --proxy http://127.0.0.1:24000 -H "x-lpm-country: us" http://lumtest.com/myip.json
```

here is bright data doc

with python requests its working, but in selenium i can`t change proxy country

I just want to run code in selenium
and dynamically change proxy targeting